# Spawn a background process in a bash function

Tags: bash, shell, unix, bash-function

I am working on writing a Bash function to start a server that needs to be started from a certain folder, but I don't want starting this server to impact my current work. I've written the following:

```
function startsrv {
        pushd .
        cd ${TRUNK}
        ${SERVERCOMMAND} & 
        popd
}
```

My variables are all set, but when this executes, I get an error regarding an unexpected semicolon in the output, it appears that Bash is inserting a semicolon after the ampersand starting `${SERVERCOMMAND}` in the background.

Is there anything I can do to start `${SERVERCOMMAND}` in the background while still using pushd and popd to make sure I end up back in my current directory?

Edit: Output of `echo ${SERVERCOMMAND}`, since it was requested:

```
yeti --server --port 8727
```

Error message:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is the value of `$SERVERCOMMAND`? You must have a semi-colon in it.

For what it's worth you can simplify the pushd/cd to one pushd:

```
pushd $TRUNK
$SERVERCOMMAND &
popd
```

Or create a subshell so the cd only affects the one command:

```
(cd $TRUNK; $SERVERCOMMAND &)
```

Comment: The pushd tip is good, but ${SERVERCOMMAND} doesn't have a semicolon, it's equal to `yeti --server --port ${YETIPORT}` YETIPORT is numeric. I get the same error when using your subshell version.

Comment: Can you give the exact error message you're getting, and also do `echo "$SERVERCOMMAND"` and show us its exact value? (The variable substitution for `${YETIPORT}` should have already been performed so you should see an actual port number, not the variable name.)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `cd -`

```
cd $TRUNK
$SERVERCOMMAND &
cd -
```

Answer (score 3):

A semicolon in `${SERVERCOMMAND}` should not trigger a syntax error unless there is a bug in `bash` itself.  The semicolon problem must be located elsewhere, in a part of the code we don't see.

Aside from the semicolon issue, there are some minor bugs in your code:

- The `${TRUNK}` variable expansion isn't quoted.  If the directory name contains whitespace, `bash` will split it into multiple fields before invoking `cd`.
- The return value of `cd ${TRUNK}` isn't checked.  If the directory doesn't exist, `bash` will invoke the server in the current directory.
- The function doesn't test whether `${SERVERCOMMAND}` might fail to execute (e.g., command not found).
- The `function` keyword and the `pushd` and `popd` commands are `bash`-specific, so this code won't run in a POSIX shell.

Here's a safer, POSIX-compatible rewrite:

```
log() { printf '%s\n' "$*"; }
error() { log "ERROR: $*" >&2; }
fatal() { error "$*"; exit 1; }

startsrv() {
    (
        cd "${TRUNK}" || fatal "failed to cd to '${TRUNK}'"
        set -- ${SERVERCOMMAND}
        command -v "$1" >/dev/null || fatal "command '$1' not found"
        command "$@" &
    ) || exit 1
}
```