# Qt Library not found while starting AVD

Tags: android

Getting following error :

```
ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:33:Qt library not found at E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\lib64\qt\lib
Could not launch 'E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe': No such file or directory
```

Can anybody help? I have tried below command also

```
ln -s Nexus_6P_API_22 Nexus_6P_API_22-x86
```

but result was :

```
ln: creating symbolic link `Nexus_6P_API_22-x86' to `Nexus_6P_API_22': No such file or directory
```

List of AVD's:

```
Nexus_4_API_14
Nexus_5X_API_22
Nexus_5_API_14
Nexus_6P_API_22
```

Comment: i am also getting this problem, did you manager to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this error by installing Android Emulator from android studio update.

You can find it in:

```
File 
-> Settings 
-> "Appearance & Behavior" 
-> "System Settings" 
-> "Android SDK" 
-> "SDK Tools" 
-> Check mark "Show Package Details"
```

My configuration is Windows 10, Android Studio 2.3, and Java 1.8.

I found the solution [in this thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235461#c14).

Answer (score 1):

For me, there was a solution in the thread referenced by Bhavin Doshi that explained the tools also need to be local. Then I used advice elsewhere on backgrounding and pushd/popd, [Spawn a background process in a bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298623/spawn-a-background-process-in-a-bash-function) .

What works nicely for me is:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager list # find out the name of my emulator    
date; pwd; ( cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools ;  emulator -avd myAvdName & ); pwd
```

With a subshell, as above, actually one does not need $ pushd adir ; ...; $ popd

Comment: Great find! Admittedly that error message is very misleading - this solved the issue right away. Thanks for pointing us in the right direction.